# Formularios combinados

Tags: c#, windows-forms

En windows Forms con c#
Tengo un formulario Viajes con otro de Tikets asociados al viaje, para el crud cuando genero un viaje nuevo, genero yo el codigo con una funcion Max(Codigo)+1. tengo un boton donde abro el formulario de los tickets, lo abro con el codigo de viaje para que se puedan generar los tickets asociados al viaje.

si dos usuarios cargan en simultaneo tengo problema con el codigo de viaje ya que ambos tienen el mismo codigo.

Como seria la mejor forma de solucionar este problema y que pueda tener el formulario tikets al momento al momento de generar los tickets es decir ya saber el codigo de viaje.

Comment: Debes reservar codigos de viaje, o asignarlos al final... el codigo de viaje, no deberia formar parte de nada, y si es obligatorio, deberia asignarse al final.. que pasa si los dos usuarios entran, pero solo uno se va? admitis agujeros?

Comment: 1) Hay un servidor intermedio o la conexión es directa a la DB? 2) el código puede ser NO numérico??? 3) Si es numérico te molesta perder algunos, por ejemplo tener el código 1,2,4,7,9 (es decir perdiste los 2,5,6 y 8; los cuales no puedes reutilizar)?